# Get hostname of AWS instance via Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just wondering how I get the hostname, i.e. the result of running 'hostname' on the command prompt, of an AWS machine (RHEL) via the Java API.

I can call the following

```
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Instance awsInstance = ...
awsInstance.getPublicIpAddress())
awsInstance.getPrivateIpAddress())
awsInstance.getPrivateDnsName())
awsInstance.getPublicDnsName())
```

But cannot find out how to get the hostname - theres no getHostname() method.

Comment: Why do you want to know that exactly? The existing methods provide plenty of information

Comment: The default hostname is the internal ip seperated by - instead of . Don't understand your problem.

Comment: Did you checked InetAddress if you are running jvm there?

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get the hostname indirectly via:

```
awsInstance.getPrivateDnsName().split("\\.")[0]
```